# List all files and directories in JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, directory

I am wanting away to list all my files and folders in a JSON but I need to be able to call the files using jQuery

Basically what I have is the following

```
public function listproductimagedirectory($rootPath) {
    $pathStack = array($rootPath);
    $contentsRoot = array();
    $contents = &$contentsRoot;
    while ($path = array_pop($pathStack)) {
       $contents[basename($path)] = array();
       $contents = &$contents[basename($path)];
       foreach (scandir($path) as $filename) {
           if ('.' != substr($filename, 0, 1)) {
               $newPath = $path.'/'.$filename;
               if (is_dir($newPath)) {
                   array_push($pathStack, $newPath);
                   $contents[basename($newPath)] = array();
               } else {
                   $contents[basename($filename)] = $newPath;
               }
           }
       }
    }
    return $contentsRoot[basename($rootPath)];
    }
```

which outputs

```
{"giftcard":{"31791_319x242_0.jpg":"..\/products\/giftcard\/31791_319x242_0.jpg","7520921_0_9999_lge_v1_m56577569834701600.jpg":"..\/products\/giftcard\/7520921_0_9999_lge_v1_m56577569834701600.jpg","AMF.jpg":"..\/products\/giftcard\/AMF.jpg","accor.jpg":"..\/products\/giftcard\/accor.jpg","accorhotel.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/accorhotel.png","cellarmasters.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/cellarmasters.png","dusk.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/dusk.png","giftca_100ath_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_100ath_lrg.png","giftca_100goo_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_100goo_lrg.png","giftca_100sun_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_100sun_lrg.png","giftca_20itu_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_20itu_lrg.png","giftca_25abc_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_25abc_lrg.png","giftca_25jay_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_25jay_lrg.png","giftca_30bra_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_30bra_lrg.png","giftca_30div_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_30div_lrg.png","giftca_40ebg_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_40ebg_lrg.png","giftca_50col_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_50col_lrg.png","giftca_50cou_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_50cou_lrg.png","giftca_50dot_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_50dot_lrg.png","giftca_50dym_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_50dym_lrg.png","giftca_50hoy_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_50hoy_lrg.png","giftca_50itu_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_50itu_lrg.png","giftca_50jac_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_50jac_lrg.png","giftca_50jea_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_50jea_lrg.png","giftca_50pet_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_50pet_lrg.png","giftca_50por_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_50por_lrg.png","giftca_50reb_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_50reb_lrg.png","giftca_50san_lrg.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/giftca_50san_lrg.png","isubscribe.jpg":"..\/products\/giftcard\/isubscribe.jpg","isubscribe.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/isubscribe.png","peteralexander.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/peteralexander.png","rydges hotel.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/rydges hotel.png","smiggle.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/smiggle.png","sportsgirl.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/sportsgirl.png","sussan.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/sussan.png","wiggles.png":"..\/products\/giftcard\/wiggles.png"}}
```

What I see and I could be wrong but there is nothing the allows me to tell the ID of the array for e.g I am use to calling a JSON by using the each function and using something like this

`obj.title` that would tell me that its the title of the json row.

Answer (score 1):

put your objects in an array... so you would have..

```
var myobject = { giftcard: [ {filename: "image1.png", path: "path"}, {filename: "image2.png", path: "path""}, {filename: "image3.png", path: "path"} etc...]}
```

then you can:

```
$.each(myobject.giftcard, function(index, image) { 
   image.filename
   image.path
});
```

Comment: @AdamSack I did that and I still get the file name as the id I call.

Comment: you dont seem to have the id in the json, if do you just want the index? if so just use index.